# I just added angularjs to my BackboneJS site using requireJS to use for rendering a few views and gradually transitioning. Should I expect problems?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, backbone.js

So, I've read in different places that `Backbone` and `angular` don't get along always, and that makes sense with respect to certain modules (like anchor link routing, since there can only be one top dog).

I went ahead and did the work to add `angular` anyway because it is clearly the better choice and there are way better plugins available for it, including a few table plugins that I am loving.

Now, I've yet to actually do this, but this has been my plan all along: use `angular` to generate and render a particular view or set of views, but always invoke it using `Backbone`.

For instance, I will need a "grid view" in the interior of one of my existing `Backbone.View`s. I am planning on booting `angular` with the root element provided by the client `Backbone.View`:

```
var ClientBBView = Backbone.View.extend({
    ...
    render: function() { 
        ... //do my normal rendering
        require(['app/app.boot'],function(appBoot) { appBoot.boot($(targetElement)); });
    }
    ...
}
```

Of course I would need to make the call specific to the view needed.

Anyway, if I do this, my intent is to demote `angular` so it doesn't try to take over the whole document. I noticed this line...

```
define([
'angular',
'app/js/app'
], function (angular, app) {
    'use strict';
    // as script is at the very bottom of the page no waiting for domReady
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']); // <-- REPLACE DOCUMENT
});
```

so that's where the targetElement parameter will go. This way, I am thinking, it won't be able to mess with my routes at least.

Are there any gotchas I should know about with this sort of patchwork use of `angular`? Is this a common use case? It seems like it would work fine but I could use some advice.

Comment: I do this, without requirejs, with document.body or even with getElementById. no problem so far. even tried with NG_DEFER_BOOTSTRAP!, but not much extra benefit with that. But rendering with Backbone, may be hard part, since angular use a lot of overhead on walking DOM, collecting directives and parsing html and expressions (limited javascript) with its own function.

Comment: @YOU, thanks for your insight. I wonder if that chatter would be better if it were not on document but on a node instead

Comment: btw, one issue I found today is angular dumping html texts into documentFragment, and walk that DOM during $compile. that would be problem with text rendering engines.